# How to draw Bar Chart from Excel File in Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, bar-chart

I'm really new in Matlab. Suppose I have a table in excel, passenger.xls, as below:

```
Id  StaName   In  Out 

1   StationA  10  80

2   StationB  50  40

3   StationC  25  45
```

How can I make a appropriate bar chart in Matlab that display `In` and `Out` by `StationName` as shown in the table above?

Could you give me a step by step instructions to do this task please? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
% A very simple example that does not attempt any checks on the input data.

% Load your Excel file into MatLab.
% Replace YourExcelFile with the correct file name
[numeric,textual,raw]=xlsread('YourExcelFile');

% Assuming that the example data starts in cell A1 and is of the format
% shown, plot the 'In' and 'Out' numeric data in a bar graph.
bar(numeric(1:end,3:end));

% Replace the numeric labels on the x axis with the values from StaName.
% Do this by setting the XTickLabel property on the current graph axis.
set(gca,'XTickLabel',textual(2:end,2));
```

Comment: Amazing, it really work!! Thank you so much, you are really helpful. If you don't mind, I have one more question. If I want to reverse the Bar Graph where, now, Y axis is a StationName while X axis is the In and Out, what is the command to do so? I tried some but it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I found it using barh. Thank you...